# Is there a way to target multiple classes with the same elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have styling for a form, a snippet of which is here:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="tel"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], textarea, select {
   height: 40px;
   padding:  10px;
}
```

I want to use this styling on several different forms (but not all) on a site. Each has its own id, for example one is .node-825 and another is .node-826. I want to know if there's a neat way to use my stylesheet to target all the forms.

I understand that I can do the following:

```
.node-825 input[type="text"], .node-825 input[type="tel"], .node-825 input[type="password"], .node-825 input[type="email"], .node-825 textarea, .node-825 select, 
.node-826 input[type="text"], .node-826 input[type="tel"], .node-826 input[type="password"], .node-826 input[type="email"], .node-826 textarea, .node-826 select {
    height: 40px;
    padding:  10px;
}
```

This does work but let's be honest, it's very messy and seems unnecessary, there must be a neater way to do this without repeating myself over and over again. There are about 10 forms I need to target so it doesn't seem right that I should have to repeat the above selectors 10 times just with one class change each time.

I'm looking for something along the lines of this:

```
.node-825, .node-856(input[type="text"], input[type="tel"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], textarea, select) {
    height: 40px;
    padding:  10px;
}
```

The above does not work but that is the kind of thing I am aiming for. Whilst I have noticed similar questions to this, none seem to be the same and answer what I am trying to do.

This is the basic format of the HTML with all the 'fluff' removed to give you an idea of the layout of each form.

```
<div id="node-825" class="blog-single-post node node-webform clearfix">
   <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also add the HTML? I think I may have an idea of how to solve this, but have to see the HTML first.

Comment: I've made the edit, I've only included a tiny snippet with all the fluff removed to give you an example. For me to put anymore would just be confusing and steer the question off course.

Comment: Not possible without some CSS preprocessor like SASS or Less, I'm afraid .... unless of course you are willing to modify the markup.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add a common class to all the form tags which you want to be affected, and use that one class in the selector instead of repeating the rules with multiple IDs.

```
<form id="node-825" class="layout_1">
  ...
</form>
<form id="node-826">
  ...
</form>
<form id="node-827" class="layout_1">
  ...
</form>
```

...and in the CSS

```
.layout_1 input[type="text"], 
.layout_1 input[type="tel"], 
.layout_1 input[type="password"], 
.layout_1 input[type="email"], 
.layout_1 textarea, 
.layout_1 select {
   height: 40px;
   padding:  10px;
}
```

...which will affect `#node-825` and `#node-827`, but not `#node-826`

Comment: Ah if only it were that easy. Whilst this would normally work, yes, I'm using Drupal and there isn't an easy way of adding a class to some forms but not others. +1 for a good answer though.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a pattern inside CSS selector:

```
[class^=node-] {
    color: red;  
}
```

This selects all elements with class starting with 'node-'.

Comment: A great idea but unfortunately a lot of the other elements that I don't want to target also start with 'node-'

Comment: You can complete this selector with the classes mentioned above. That would target the exact elements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. How would I target .node-825 and .node-856 ?